# How do I combine images on a webpage with PHP?

Tags: php, image-manipulation

I have a website with a customizable avatar. I need to know how to take two items and merge them together into one image. I've searched places, but I can't find the thing I need! I'm a little bit new to PHP, I do have my own site, but somethings really confuse me, so please don't just send me some random link and expect me to understand.

Comment: Check out the GD image functions in PHP. If you don't want to learn them, hire someone.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm really confused about GD. Are there any tutorials on this?

Comment: See the docs, and the comments on them. WARNING: Probability of "random link" nearing 100%!!! — http://us2.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php

Answer (score 0):

You could try IMagick, specifically, the [compositeImage](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagick-compositeimage.php) function. I've never used this myself, so what follows is sort of a guess:

```
<?php 
$canvas = new Imagick();
$canvas->setSize(100,50);

$first = new Imagick('first.jpg'); 
$second = new Imagick('second.jpg'); 

$canvas->compositeImage($first, COMPOSITE_COPY, 0, 0);
$canvas->compositeImage($second, COMPOSITE_COPY, 50, 0);

$canvas->writeImage('final.jpg');
```

Like I said, kind of a guess but I'm pretty sure a variation of that will work.

Comment: Ok I'll try that. I've tried GD but I need to merge multiple images.